# Excel VBA open files from download dialog

Tags: java, excel, vba, internet-explorer

Require help here, am trying to use VBA to interact with a Download dialog box.

unfortunately wasn't able to post the image as i don't have the require reputation to do so.

but it is just a simple dialog box with only 3 option.

1) open
2) save as
3) save

What i am trying to do is, instead of window/excel prompting the dialog box, Excel VBA will directly open it. Anyone knows how? tried (SendKeys "{TAB}", True/SendKeys "{ENTER}", True) but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this as it is worked for me on IE9:

[image: For below showed download]

1. Copy file `C:\Windows\System32\UIAutomationCore.dll` file to users Documents i.e `C:\Users\admin\Documents` then add reference `UIAutomationClient` to your macro file.
2. Paste below code in your module:

   ```
       Option Explicit
       Dim ie As InternetExplorer
       Dim h As LongPtr
       Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As LongPtr, ByVal hWnd2 As LongPtr, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As LongPtr

   Sub Download()
       Dim o As IUIAutomation
       Dim e As IUIAutomationElement
       Set o = New CUIAutomation
       h = ie.Hwnd
       h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
       If h = 0 Then Exit Sub

       Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
       Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
       Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Save")

       Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
       Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
       Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
       Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
       InvokePattern.Invoke
   End Sub
   ```

Try at your end.